# order a column in a query object by length with QoQ in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

Is it possible to sort a query object by the length of a varchar column using Query of Queries in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this entirely with QoQ, no: the [QoQ implementation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html) does not provide a `len()` function.  Instead, you could get the database to provide the length data for you.

In the original query add:

```
len(fieldYouNed) as fieldYouNedLen
```

In the QoQ then use:

```
SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY fieldYouNedLen
```

Answer (score 2):

In Coldfusion 10, you could use the sortBy() function of the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#sortBy) like so:

```
sortedQuery = _.sortBy(queryObject, function(row) {
   return len(row.column);
});
```

(Disclaimer: I created this library)

Comment: I saw Russ just blogged it recently it's quite nice and looks nice.

Comment: Thanks, I hope to add Railo 4 support soon too